# Differentiate between Android Browser and Chrome for Android

Tags: android, web

I am making a mobile site and I have a problem on a Samsung Galaxy s3. The thing is that my chosen font-size looks fine in Chrome, but is too small in the native Android browser.

On the other hand if I increase font size, it is too big on Chrome.

Is there any way to target Android browser, or to alter it's behavior?

Comment: May be it will be like the `Difference between chrome and firefox for desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

visit this page from your android browser:  http://whatsmyuseragent.com/
you will get the user agent of your browser and that is an attribute you can differentiate browsers by.